# cursor in mysql flask not working properly

Tags: python, mysql, macos, flask

**this the module and configuration section of the app.py file.**

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, flash, request, logging, redirect, 
url_for, session
from data import Blogs
from flaskext.mysql import MySQL
from wtforms import Form, StringField, TextAreaField, PasswordField, 
validators
from passlib.hash import sha256_crypt

mysql = MySQL()

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_HOST'] = 'localhost'
app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_USER'] = 'root'
app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_PORT'] = 5000
app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_PASSWORD'] = '123456'
app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_DB'] = 'myflaskapp'
app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_CURSORCLASS'] = 'DictCursor'

mysql.init_app(app)
```

**this is the @app.route section**

```
@app.route('/register', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def register():

#have used wtforms     

form = RegisterForm(request.form)
   if request.method == 'POST' and form.validate(): 
       id = form.id.data
       name = form.name.data
       username = form.username.data
       email = form.email.data
       password = sha256_crypt.encrypt(str(form.password.data))
       college = form.college.data
       year = form.year.data


       # Create cursor

       cur = mysql.get_db().cursor()


       # Execute query

       cur.execute("INSERT INTO users(id, name, username, email, password, 
       college, year) VALUES(%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)", (id, name, 
       username, email, password, college, year))



       flash('You are now registered and can log in', 'success')

       return redirect(url_for('login'))
    return render_template('register.html', form=form)
```

**I'm getting 
  Method Not Allowed
  The method is not allowed for the requested URL.
  please do help me out with this issue.**

this is on macosx

please do help me out.
thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Change `VALUES(%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)", (id, name, username, email, password, college, year))`

to:

`VALUES('{}', '{}' ,'{}', '{}', '{}', '{}', '{}')".format(id, name, username, email, password, college, year))`